# turn certain parts of array to numbers

Tags: php, arrays, string, integer

Hey so i have an array that looks like this.
I got the  information fro the array from a database.

{"Id":"2","Name":"Tim","number":"2345","faculty":"DT","grade":"1"},

what can i do to turn the Id and **number** to a number and not a string?

the code looks like this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root',
'', 'personen');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Keine Verbindung zur Datenbank möglich: " .
    mysqli_connect_error();

}

$ausgabe="SELECT studenten.Id,studenten.Name, studenten.Matrikelnummer, studenten.Studiengang,noten.Note  FROM studenten JOIN Noten ON studenten.Id= noten.StudentId  ";
 

$ergebnis = $mysqli -> query($ausgabe);



if($ergebnis != false) {
    $daten = array();
    while($row = $ergebnis -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $daten[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($daten);
    }
   





   
    $mysqli -> close();
```

Comment: SQL does not support arrays so this question is clearly not about SQL.  I removed the tag.

Comment: Can you show the code which produces this data.

Comment: @ Nigel Ren yes i edited the question

Comment: `echo json_encode( $daten, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );` should do it

Comment: @ Nigel Ren  thank you it works now